# Why is the volume of the solid of revolution between two graphs $\int_{0}^{b}\pi[f^2(x)-g^2(x)]dx$ instead of $\int_{0}^{b}\pi[f(x)-g(x)]^2dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definition, volume

Let $f$ and $g$ be two non-negative functions which are integrable over the interval $[0,b]$ and satisfy $f \geq g$ on $[0,b]$. I am told that the volume of the solid of revolution created by rotating the region between the graphs of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ about the x-axis is given as $\int_{0}^{b} \pi f^2(x)dx-\int_{0}^{b}\pi g^2(x)dx$, or $\int_{0}^{b}\pi[f^2(x)-g^2(x)]dx$.

I think I understand how to see this integral calculation visually.
The solid of revolution created by the region under the smaller graph "carves out" a hollow in the solid of revolution created by the region under the bigger graph, and the volume of the carved out solid is what we obtain through the integral calculation. More specifically, one can think of summing up the volumes of infinitesimally thin annuli over the interval, with the inner and outer radii of the annulus at some $x $ on the interval given by $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ respectively.

However, I don't understand why the volume is not instead defined as $\int_{0}^{b}\pi[f(x)-g(x)]^2dx$, as this seems to follow naturally from how the area between between the two graphs would be found. So in this scenario, you find the volume of a solid of revolution created by summing up the areas of infinitesimally thin circles of radius $f(x)-g(x)$ at some given $x$ in the interval. It seems as if you could define the solid of revolution this way instead. Why is the volume not defined through this calculation? Is the other calculation more useful?

Am I missing something obvious here? Is the way I see the calculation wrong? If not, is there a good reason why the volume is defined the way it is?

Comment: The given integral is not the *definition* of said volume. Rather, it is a formula for *computing* the (already defined beforehand) volume. The *definition* is typically done in terms of unions of disjoint cubes. This definition (and as a consequence: the integral formula) has turned out to be extremely useful because it grasps the concept of volume in our everyday world

Comment: Am I wrong in thinking that two different solids of revolution could be created by subtracting $f(x)$ from $g(x)$? I.e, you could create one by subtracting the volume of the solid of revolution created by rotating the ordinate set of $g(x)$ about the x-axis from the solid of revolution created by rotating the ordinate set of $f(x)$ about the x-axis, and another by rotating the ordinate set of $f(x)-g(x)$ about the x-axis? Would these not be two different solids of revolution with two different volumes, both created by thinking about the region between $f(x)$ & $g(x)$?

Comment: Just try it out on a simple example of a "pipe" (two coaxial cylinders inside each other,  i.e. where $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are constant). The volume is obtained correctly when you use the formula with $f(x)^2-g(x)^2$ but not when you use $(f(x)-g(x))^2$ simply because the area of a "ring" between two circles with radii $r_1$ and $r^2$ is *not* $(r_1-r_2)^2\pi$ but $(r_1^2-r_2^2)\pi$.

Comment: What you seem to want to use is a sort of "Cavalieri's principle" but it just does not work - does not give correct results. The same logic would tell you that the area of the ring should be $(r_1-r_2)^2\pi$ which is the wrong result - the principle cannot be applied in this case!

Comment: But why do we want to find the area around a ring with inner radius $g(x)$ and outer radius $f(x)$ rather than say, some cylinder of radius $(f(x)-g(x))$? If someone asked you to find the volume of the solid of revolution created by the region between $f(x)$ & $g(x)$, couldn't you interpret that two different ways?

Comment: The bottom line is - one formula gives the right result, the other gives the wrong result, so you pick the first one rather than the second one. The first formula is easily proven by subtracting the area of the inner circle ($r_2^2\pi$) from the area of the outer circle ($r_1^2\pi$). The second formula, being not equal to the first formula, is just plainly wrong. I suppose you are not asking why is, in most cases, $(r_1^2-r_2^2)\pi\ne(r_1-r_2)^2\pi$? However, accepting that, and accepting that the first formula is correct, the second must be incorrect!

Comment: In maths we don't use the formulae that "look right" - we use those that are underpinned by a *proof* that they work. The first formula has been proven. The second is not less wrong because it looks nicer.

Comment: @StinkingBishop I think I have explained what exactly my question is somewhat poorly, see my comments on the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some intuition, consider revolving the region between the graphs of $y=y_0$ and $y=y_1$ on $[a,b]$. For definiteness let's say $y_1>y_0>0$. Now the region in space that you are creating is the space between two cylinders whose axes are the $x$ axis. The inner cylinder has radius $y_0$ (the distance between the bottom of the segment and the axis of revolution) and the outer cylinder has radius $y_1$ (the distance between the top of the segment and the axis of revolution). So the cross sectional area is $\pi y_1^2 - \pi y_0^2$ (the area between two concentric circles). You would have $\pi (y_1-y_0)^2$ if you revolved around $y=y_0$ instead of $y=0$, because then there would be no separation between the axis and the segment.

What you described, which is commonly called the washer method, is just the generalization of this to the case when the radii depend on $x$.

Comment: I understand how the volume is calculated. What I don't understand is why this volume is calculated rather than the volume of the solid of revolution created by rotating the ordinate set of $f(x)-g(x)$ around the x-axis.

Comment: @MahdiRkioui It comes down to the actual geometry of the situation. In my example, you're revolving this line segment between $(x,y_0)$ and $(x,y_1)$ around the $x$ axis. The axis of revolution is therefore separated from the segment by a distance of $y_0$. That separation is crucial; if you instead revolve around $y=y_0$, you would get a cross sectional area of $\pi (y_1-y_0)^2$ instead.

Comment: Right, I just don't understand why we don't want that cross sectional area instead. The first is more useful?

Comment: @MahdiRkioui It's not about applicability, really. It's about the geometry. So maybe it will help to rephrase again. If you revolve a segment of length $L$ around an axis oriented perpendicular to that segment, and the axis is a distance $d$ away from the segment, the region you make is an annulus of inner radius $d$ and outer radius $d+L$. (If you don't know the word "annulus", it is the same thing as the region between a circle of radius $d$ and a concentric circle of radius $d+L$.)

Comment: So we can think of the first calculation as "preserving" the information of the distance $d$ from the axis, while the calculation with radius $(f(x)-g(x))$ sets d=0 and so is therefore wrong?

Comment: @MahdiRkioui Right. The version that ends up with a radius of $|f(x)-g(x)|$ is what you get when you revolve around $y=\min \{ |f(x)|,|g(x)| \}$, which makes the segments you're revolving be a distance $0$ away from the axis. But this is not the same geometry, because you have changed what axis you're revolving around.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the notation at the end. But I think I understand now why the second calculation is wrong. The first takes into account that the region between $f(x)$ & $g(x)$ is some distance $d$ up from the axis of rotation, is this the right way of thinking about it?

Comment: @MahdiRkioui Yes that is correct.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the extended explanation. Could you edit your post to include what you have explained here, so that I can tick it as an answer? The answer itself doesn't address my question, but I think this is due to poor wording in my initial post.

Comment: @MahdiRkioui Does this help? I really am not saying anything meaningfully different in the comments rather than the answer, but I added some parentheticals to clarify a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a region bounded by the lines $x=0$ and $x=b$ and the curves $y=f(x)$ and $y=g(x)$, with $c\le g(x)\le f(x)$. Suppose we revolve this region about a line $y=c$ and use the washer method to find the volume. Consult the sketch below.

[image]

The sketch shows one such washer, whose volume is

$$\pi (f(x)^2 - g(x)^2) \Delta x$$

The volume of a cylinder is $\pi R^2 h$, where the radius is $R$ and the height is $h$. From this cylinder we cut out another cylinder with a smaller radius $r$. The resulting washer has volume $\pi R^2h-\pi r^2h = \pi (R^2-r^2)h$, and we just replace symbols with $f,g,\Delta x$ accordingly, make $\Delta x\to0$, and take infinitely many washers to get

$$V = \pi \int_0^b (f(x)^2-g(x)^2) \, dx$$

(assuming we revolve about the $x$-axis so $c=0$)

On the other hand, integrating with $(f(x)-g(x))^2$ amounts to applying the disk method on a single function $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$, for which the volume would be

$$V' = \pi \int_0^b (f(x)-g(x))^2 \, dx$$

[image]